# Leaflet - how to add a static function to class?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'd like to add a function to [L.GeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) called "getLatLngPath", which will take a geojson object and shoot out a single array of latlngs for any LineString or MultiLineString features in the geojson.  Simple.

Because I'm not overriding any code, and it's a static function, my thought was to use the [include()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#class) method in the hopes I could access the function as L.GeoJSON.getLatLngPath(...).  Code:

```
L.GeoJSON.include({
    /*
     * Returns a single array containing all the latlngs from each LineString feature
     */
    getLatLngPath: function(geojson, reverse) {
        reverse = typeof reverse === undefined ?  false : reverse;
        var path = [];
        if (geojson.type === 'FeatureCollection') {
            for(var i=0; i < geojson.features.length; i++) {
                // Recursively call this function on each feature
                path = path.concat(this.getLatLngPath(geojson.features[i]));  
            }
        } else if (geojson.type === 'Feature' && (geojson.geometry.type === 'LineString' || geojson.geometry.type === 'MultiLineString')) {
            return L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs( // function existing in L.GeoJSON
                geojson.geometry.coordinates,
                geojson.geometry.type === 'LineString' ? 0 : 1, // Need one more level deep if a MultiLineString
                reverse);       
        }
        return this._pruneDuplicates(path);     
    },

    /*
     * Prunes duplicate-adjacent latlngs
     */
    _pruneDuplicates: function (path) {
        var i=1;
        while (i < path.length){
            if (path[i-1][0] == path[i][0] && path[i-1][1] == path[i][1]) {
                path.splice(i, 1);
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
});
```

(Note, code is not tested yet, and it's not relevant to this question.)

Calling L.GeoJSON.getLatLngPath(...) doesn't work -- it says it is not a function.  However, it works if I call the factory method (which just returns a "new" instance of it):

```
L.geoJson().getLatLngPath(...);
```

I don't mean to quibble, but this is ugly.  I shouldn't need to create a new object for a static method  How can I make my function a static method called right from L.GeoJSON?

Answer (score 1):

The method is available on the class prototype:

```
L.GeoJSON.prototype.getLatLngPath(...);
```

Comment: That does work.  Still seems wrong that I can call other static methods directly from L.GeoJSON, but my methods need to invoke the prototype.  Is there no way to call the static method directly from L.GeoJSON?  Or perhaps extend the class and just call it something else?